# Horizontally scrollable svg element?

Tags: html, css, svg, material-design-lite

I would like to place a svg image in the middle of my webpage:
[image: design mockup]

The image should be shown partially horizontally - for ex., 1/3 of the image should be shown initially, user should be able to scroll it horizontally (to see remaining 2/3 part). How should I achieve that? (it should work in mobile browsers also).

Just in case this is important - I use [Material Design Lite](http://www.getmdl.io) as a framework.

Upd. It should be possible to scroll it with mouse/tap and scroll bar should be hidden. See the demo at jsfiddle.net/and7ey/pLf5namm/embedded/result/.

Comment: Giving `body` and `html` a width of `100%` and for the SVG `300%` does not work?

Comment: @Sirko, it displays 1/3 of the image, but there is no way to scroll it.

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ogvdv8d5/ I get a window scrollbar. If you want a scrollbar just for the SVG, wrap it in another `<div>` tag with `width: 100%; overflow-y: scroll;"`.

Comment: Thanks, @Sirko. This is almost what I need. I haven't mentioned it initially, but it should be possible to scroll it with mouse/tap and scroll bar should be hidden. Can I achieve that somehow? And, could you please post your reply as answer, so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow-x`.

```
svg {
   overflow-x: scroll;
}
```